# Plot xyplot lines correctly after re-ordering factors

Tags: r, plot, data-visualization, lattice

When I make `xyplot` with line connections before reordering factors, it gives me a nice, sequential connections between data points:

```
library(lattice)
fin <- read.csv("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2505196/unc_vall.csv", header=T)
xyplot(acceptability ~ character | motion, data=fin, col=1, 
       aspect="xy", layout=c(6,1), type="o", scales = list(x = list(rot = 90)))
```

[image]

Then I reorder factors, and everything gets screwed:

```
fin$character <- factor(fin$character, levels = c("battle","klank","manny",
                        "skelly","zombie","loman","himan"))
```

[image]

Reordering factors' levels works fine, the values go where they should, but somehow the order of line connections stays the same. It doesn't occur to me how I could change my reordering to make it work.

EDIT: I should add that solution should be universal enough to work for both `xyplot` and `xYplot` from the package `Hmisc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lines get drawn in the order they appear in the data, I think. So if you want to get a correct ordering you could do:

```
xyplot(acceptability ~ character | motion, data=fin[order(fin$character),], col=1, 
aspect="xy", layout=c(6,1), type="o", scales = list(x = list(rot = 90)))
```

Notice only the `data` argument changed.

Answer (score 2):

Setting `type=c("a", "p")` (in place of `type="o"`) will do the trick:

```
xyplot(acceptability ~ character | motion, data=fin, col=1,
       aspect="xy", layout=c(6,1), type=c("a", "p"), 
       scales = list(x = list(rot = 90)))
```

Comment: That's neat for `xyplot` @Josh, but unfortunately doesn't work for `xYplot` from `Hmisc` - should have mentioned that this solution should apply to both type of plots...

Comment: @GeekOnAcid -- Gotcha. If you delve into `xYplot` and figure out a clever solution, would you please alert me with a note here? Cheers.

Comment: Sure, I will give you a shout. @nograpes solution actually works with `xYplot`, but I still would like to find have panel-driven alternative.

Answer (score 2):

I think a better solution is to treat the data as they are rather than fake things - the x-axis here is a factor and you should respect that. You can achieve what you want using `panel.average()` but we also need to call `panel.xyplot()` too, in a custom `panel` function:

```
xyplot(acceptability ~ character | motion, data=fin, col=1, 
       aspect="xy", layout=c(6,1), scales = list(x = list(rot = 90)),
       panel = function(x, y, ...) {
           panel.xyplot(x, y, ...)
           panel.average(x, y, horizontal = FALSE, ...)
       })
```

Thanks fully there is an easier way as the `type = "a"` shortcut will add a `panel.average()` call for us, so change the plot to:

```
xyplot(acceptability ~ character | motion, data=fin, col=1, 
       aspect="xy", layout=c(6,1),
       type = c("p","a"), ## specify the type!
       scales = list(x = list(rot = 90)))
```

Comment: Again, it's fine for `xyplot` but unfortunately fails with `xYplot` from `Hmisc`. Still, both yours and @Josh are very neat solutions that I would prefer to use rather then over-re-ordering.